# which property is to user to make node of JTree as checkbox?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am working in a project in which it require to add checkbox in JTree node
is there any property for it.

Comment: Take a look on this post, this is what u need:
[How to add checkbox to Jtree node to manage multiselection][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870908/how-to-add-checkbox-to-jtree-node-to-manage-multiselection/12870909#12870909

Answer (score 2):

You will have to customize implementation of [TreeCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and [TreeCellEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). Check out this link it has implementation about how to add checkbox to JTree nodes.