# JTree with tristate checkbox - selected parent in relation to children

Tags: checkbox, parent, jtree, children, tri-state-logic

How can I realize a JTree with tristate checkbox where selected parent select all children and in the reverse case deselected child parent checkbox became light gray color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add checkbox to JTree node to manage multiselection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870908/how-to-add-checkbox-to-jtree-node-to-manage-multiselection)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has already been answered here:
[How to add checkbox to JTree node to manage multiselection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870908/how-to-add-checkbox-to-jtree-node-to-manage-multiselection)

This is a fully functional example of what I understand that you're trying to do. Hope this helps!