# How to add Checkbox in Jtree using window builder in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am developing an App, I am using Eclipse kepler for this. I want to know how to create `Jtree` with `Jcheckbox` for multiple selection with the help of window builder in eclipse kepler. I tried to search for this in web, but not able to get any satisfactory links/tutorials for this.

Could anyone suggest any links for this purpose?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870909/960778

Comment: Mr.Apurv, but i am using window builder. so i just drag the JTree from palette. So how can i convert the node as checkbox? plz help me..